# display image on jsp src from the database with image url

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot

In the spring-boot project, I have an image path on the database that references the URL of an image in the computer desktop directory/file. I have been attempting to render the image source in the DB to the image tag that references the desktop directory but it not displaying.

Here is my snippet

```
  <img width="180" height="170" src="${img}" alt="passport" /> </div>
                                        <hr>
```

upon consoling the image path, I have this

```
file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/uploads/4.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serve any resource (included images) with an absolute file system path. The path, i.e. the string that you put inside the "src" attribute must be a relative path (ex. ./uploads/4.jpg) or a well formed URL.

Since you are working with dynamic pages like JSP, it means that you have a web server that must serve these resources. The images must be on the server too (and you must build the URL that point to them), otherwise there is no way to show them in the page.